# signInWithEmailAndPassword failed: Second argument "password" must be a valid string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am trying to set up a simple authentification.it worked in ionic 1.X but it didn't work in a webapp using angularJs.it's the same code.somehow it didn't work.tried adding "" but it didn't work
here's my code

```js
     $scope.emailPassLogin = function () {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword($scope.email, $scope.pwd)
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
          }).catch(function (error) {
          // Handle Errors here.
          $scope.error = error;
          $scope.message = error.message;
        });
      };
```

the ng-model is present in the view

```html
 <form class="form-signin" role="form">
            <input  type="text" ng-Model="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Adresse Email" required="" autofocus="">
            <input  type="password" ng-Model="pwd" class="form-control" placeholder="mot de passe" required="">
            
        <button ng-click="emailPassLogin()"  type="submit">Se Connecter</button>
      </form>
```

you see it's pretty straight-forward.Yet somehow the function works in Ionic but not in webapp angularjs

[image: error capture]

thank you for the help

Comment: Didn't you forget to declare `$scope.pwd`?

Answer (score 1):

`ng-Model` should be `ng-model`. It is case sensitive. Your 2 html input tags then become:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Adresse Email" required="" autofocus="">
<input type="password" ng-model="pwd" class="form-control" placeholder="mot de passe" required="">
```

Comment: still the same result

Comment: @RatedAce - add `<p>Email: {{email}}</p>` to your HTML to see if your model is being populated while you type in your input. Do the same with password.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button ng-click="login()"
```

I don't see a login function in the controller.My angularjs is a little rusty but I think you need to have that named function in the controller you are using for your component.

Comment: yes i forgot that i tried another function.it still gives me the same result

Answer (score 0):

i made it work.here's what i did

```js
      $scope.user1=[];
      $scope.login=function(){
        
             
             firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword($scope.user1.email,$scope.user1.pwd)
             .then(function(firebaseUser){
                   console.log("Signeds: "+firebaseUser.uid);
                   window.localStorage.setItem("email",firebaseUser.email);
                    
        
                   
             }).catch(function(error){
                   console.error("Authenticationed: "+error);
             });
             
          }
```

```html
<form class="form-signin" role="form">
            <input  type="text" ng-model="user.email"  placeholder="Adresse Email" required="">
            
            <input  type="password" ng-model="user.pwd"  placeholder="mot de passe" required="">
           
        <button ng-click="login()"  type="submit">Se Connecter</button>
      </form>
```

added the user in ng-model and in js file